# Getting Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="None"]"} Python when using selenium

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to use selenium to help me write a auto-apply bot on linkedin. I'm having trouble selecting the "Jobs" element on the linked in website after logging in. The code looks like this:

```
from unicodedata import name
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import json
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep
from sympy import Id           

class EasyApplyLinkedIn ():


    def __init__(self,data):            
        """param initialization"""
        self.email =data ["email"]
        self.password = data["password"]
        self.keywords = data["keywords"]
        self.location = data["location"] 
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'ApplicationBot\driver_path\chromedriver.exe')
        

    def loginLinkedIn (self):
        self.driver.get("""https://www.linkedin.com/loginsession_redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Elinkedin%2Ecom%2Fcompany%2Flogin&fromSignIn=true&trk=organization_guest_nav-header-signin""")

## Introduce email and password and hit enter 
        login_email =self.driver.find_element(By.NAME,'session_key')
        login_email.clear ()
        # basically use the sendkeys fxn to send our info to the page
        login_email.send_keys(self.email)   

        login_password =self.driver.find_element(By.NAME,'session_password')
        login_password.clear ()
        # basically use the sendkeys fxn to send our info to the page
        login_password.send_keys(self.password)
        login_password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    def job_search (self):
        ## clicking on the job button 
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        searchDriver = self.driver.find_element()
```

The below code is where I'm having trouble specifically.

```
        jobs_link  =searchDriver(By.LINK_TEXT,'Jobs')
        clicl_jobs_link= searchDriver.click
        sleep (1)
        
    
        job_box = searchDriver(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='global-nav']/div/nav/ul/li[7]/button/div/div/li-icon/svg/path")              
        searchDriver.clear()
        send_keyword = searchDriver.send_keys(self.keywords)
        sleep (1)

        ## specify location
        location_box = searchDriver(By.XPATH,"//input[starts-with(@id,'jobs-search-box-location']")                #find via xml path expression
        searchDriver.clear()
        send_location = searchDriver.send_keys(self.location)
        sleep (1)
        ## hitting enter
        searchDriver.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

I even input some wait time, I've also tried longer wait times than what's in the code but it still doesn't work

```
if __name__ =='__main__':
    with open ('E:\Job\ApplicationBot\config.json') as config_files:                         
        data = json.load(config_files)
    
    bot = EasyApplyLinkedIn (data)
    bot.loginLinkedIn()
    sleep (5)
    bot.job_search()
```

This is the error message I'm getting:
[9080:29296:0720/161241.697:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)]
[16:12:41.697] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read
descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system
is not functioning. (0x1F)
[9080:29296:0720/161241.716:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)]
[16:12:41.716] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read
descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system
is not functioning. (0x1F)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "e:\Job\ApplicationBot\main.py", line 79, in 
bot.job_search()
File "e:\Job\ApplicationBot\main.py", line 44, in job_search
searchDriver = self.driver.find_element()
File "C:\Users\lihua\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-
packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 857, in
find_element
return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
File "C:\Users\lihua\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-
packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 435, in
execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Users\lihua\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-
packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in
check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no
such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css
selector","selector":"[id="None"]"}
(Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.114)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
Ordinal0 [0x005756B3+2184883]
Ordinal0 [0x0050E5F1+1762801]
Ordinal0 [0x00423DA8+802216]
Ordinal0 [0x00451B40+990016]
Ordinal0 [0x00451DDB+990683]
Ordinal0 [0x0047EC32+1174578]
Ordinal0 [0x0046CB54+1100628]
Ordinal0 [0x0047CF52+1167186]
Ordinal0 [0x0046C926+1100070]
Ordinal0 [0x00446EA0+945824]
Ordinal0 [0x00447D96+949654]
GetHandleVerifier [0x00814192+2704034]
GetHandleVerifier [0x0080687D+2648461]
GetHandleVerifier [0x0060119A+529066]
GetHandleVerifier [0x00600006+524566]
Ordinal0 [0x00514F2B+1789739]
Ordinal0 [0x00519978+1808760]
Ordinal0 [0x00519A65+1808997]
Ordinal0 [0x00522A01+1845761]
BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76CAFA29+25]
RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77A87A9E+286]
RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77A87A6E+238]

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is happening.  Please update your question to include the full error message traceback.

Comment: yes sir, I have updated it, let me know if that's not what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

I think this line of code is the problem:

```
searchDriver = self.driver.find_element()
```

What is the purpose of this code?  You're telling it to search, but you haven't told it what to search *for*.

So I'm guessing the function defaults to searching by id, but since you didn't give it an id, you get the `id=None` error.